# Does anyone definitively know if API Gateway and cognito are hipaa compliant while using lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, hipaa

So to state the obvious, lambda is not at this time HIPAA compliant. API Gateway (without caching) and cognito are HIPAA compliant. API Gateway allows the use of lambda functions, e.g. for authentication.

My confusion lies that the only clarification under API Gateway is "it is hipaa compliant unless you cache data", but they do not mention anything about lambda. Does this imply we can indeed use lambda only within the API Gateway world, to communicate to cognito?

Comment: No it does not imply that at all. You can't process PHI data with AWS Lambda at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Lambda is not a HIPAA Eligible Services currently, your application will not be HIPAA compliant if you are using Lambda as the backend integration.

Answer (score 2):

AWS occasionally adds services to its BAA. API Gateway, Lambda functions, and Cognito are all now covered - https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/hipaa-eligible-services-reference/